# Is it possible to use Harbor Replication Rules to mirror Docker Images by digest?

Tags: docker, containers, harbor

I am looking to mirror Docker images to a [Harbor](https://goharbor.io/) instance based on tags and digests.

My standard approach thus far has involved creating [Harbor Replication Rules](https://goharbor.io/docs/1.10/administration/configuring-replication/create-replication-rules/). This works well for replicating Docker images with specific tags, however I cannot find a way to replicate based on an image digest (e.g. `ubuntu@sha256:82becede498899ec668628e7cb0ad87b6e1c371cb8a1e597d83a47fac21d6af3`).

I understand that adding a Replication Rule based on a digest means that the image should only be pulled once, so this is probably a bit of an odd use-case for Replications (which aim to pull down updated images over time).

My alternative solution would be to pull the image (`docker pull ubuntu@sha256:82becede498899ec668628e7cb0ad87b6e1c371cb8a1e597d83a47fac21d6af3`) and then push it to Harbor directly if this isn't possible.

I have tried the following Replication Rules, none of which replicate the desired image:

- 'Tag' 'matching' 'sha256:82becede498899ec668628e7cb0ad87b6e1c371cb8a1e597d83a47fac21d6af3'
- 'Tag' 'matching' '@sha256:82becede498899ec668628e7cb0ad87b6e1c371cb8a1e597d83a47fac21d6af3'
- 'Tag' 'matching' '20.04@sha256:82becede498899ec668628e7cb0ad87b6e1c371cb8a1e597d83a47fac21d6af3'

I have also tried 'Tag' 'matching' '20.04' and this succeeded, but did not have the correct digest.

Comment: For those following along, I ended up running a script on a timer to run `crane copy` to copy the images from the remote repository into Harbor, which also maintained the image digest. https://github.com/google/go-containerregistry/blob/main/cmd/crane/doc/crane_copy.md